# What does (\\&|$) regex matches

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to understand what does the regular expression `(\\&|$)` matches in a URL?

Comment: No need to escape `&` so it can be `(&|$)` which matches ampersand OR end of input.

Comment: Yep, I didn't do that, that's the reason I would like to understand what it does.

Comment: Downvoters, down vote with a reason please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that is in a regular expression it will match `\&` or the end of the string, but `\&` is not usually found in an URL.

If that is in a string literal that is used to create a regular expression, then the double backslashes will be a single in the regular expression, and then it matches `&` or the end of the string, which makes more sense.

Answer (score 3):

This will match "\&" or the end of the string.